# UIView expand but not overlap

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview

I have a simple design question but can't seem to find the simplest answers.

Having say 10 UIViews aligned from top to bottom with no overlap. If I want to expand the height of one of them, how to I move the others so no overlapping occurs?

Here's my three thoughts, love to hear yours:

1. Calculate each views origin y. Very messy I think.
2. Use tableview. Seems to complex to solve a simple problem. And maybe old school since tables are old school in html. But more clean.
3. Use constraints on all views. Seems simple and clean, but maybe a bit to complex to work with?

Have I forgotten anything obvious?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would certainly go with (3) for a few reasons:

- Flexibility - literally: You'll be able to describe what you want to happen and let AutoLayout take care of the nitty-gritty calculations.
- Flexibility - figuratively:  You won't have to worry (as much) about your application displaying correctly on a variety of different devices.

Yes, AutoLayout can be a bit more complex to work with at times, especially in the beginning, but I promise you: it's worth it in the long run.

Here's some code to get you started. The below constraints are for 5 views. The first `UIView` will have a height of greater than or equal to `myViewHeight`, which is defined below to be 20. The subsequent 4 views will be equal to `myViewHeight`.

```
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[_myView(>=myViewHeight)][_myView(==myViewHeight)][_myView(==myViewHeight)][_myView(==myViewHeight)][_myView(==myViewHeight)]-|"
                                                           options:0
                                                           metrics:@{@"myViewHeight": @20}
                                                             views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_myView)]];
```

Comment: Thanks. Your example seems easy enough. I will give it a shot with constraints. What does the notation "V:" means?

Comment: @Nam It's the Visual Format language for AutoLayout. [Here](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/31/visual-format-language-for-autolayout/) is a good writeup on it, though Apple has plenty of docs on it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH3) as well.

Comment: @Nam Also - the above constraints don't take into account the width. You'll need more constraints for that. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Jared! I'm also interested in if there are other design patterns that can be used, so feel free to add your comment.